# How to convert iphone application to Android using Titanium?

Tags: titanium

I have implemented iphone application using Titanium..But I want to convert in to android application.

Is it possible doing small chnges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are changes, but not major changes. Here is what i would do in my case?

- Understand How iPhone works and Android works. Compare them in terms
  of working model and OS Architecture. This will purely give you more idea on how to make an real Android App... else you would end up cloning your iPhone feel to Android again.
- List out all the components i have used in iPhone and check out the
  similar component available for me to replace. { For instance,
  TableView has a delete option for iPhone and not for Android }
- I would remove the back button implemented in iPhone and check how i
  can move between windows with the Android BackKey.
- Styles and Animation i have used in iPhone will not be the same for
  Android. I think they don't have full supported ones too.

For example: style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.BIG,

Answer (score 0):

maybe you experience some performance differences depending on your implementation since the javascript engine is not the same. if so, you maybe need to restructure your app to ensure a performance enhancement.